# {% load staticfiles %} - Does it pre-load all recursively or on demand?

Tags: django, static

In django I'm curious concerning the {% load staticfiles %} template directive.

In static files I have a sass directory, and sass in turn can have a cache which gets quite large. I'm not inquiring of 'best practice' though, but in any case are all files pre-loaded or not?

If I'm only using, for instance, fonts, bootstrap, a personal stylesheet, etc...is it going to load all the things I'm not using?

Very curious about this. I don't want to use up more resources than needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've completely misunderstood what the `load` tag does. All it does is make a *template tag library* available for the template to use: in this case, the "staticfiles" library which includes the definition of the `{% static %}` tag. Without that load statement, you can't use that tag.

It doesn't do anything with the staticfiles itself - indeed it can't, loading them is a matter for the browser, which will do whatever is in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I got the impression it brings all the static files into memory for reference. Much appreciated.